# Execute MySQL Query batch file

Tags: mysql, batch-file

Hi everyone here is my problem.

I'm trying to run this sql query:

```
select *columns*  from table  *left joins*  where *conditions*  and column >= date_sub(current_date(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR)   order by column INTO OUTFILE 'C:\path\file.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

Through this file.bat code:

```
echo select... | mysql -u user -p******* -D database
```

But the output file is not made, instead a weird file named "date_sub(current_date()" file with no extension is made, this file contains information about mysql, like commands, version and other stuff which tells me this part of the query is creating conflict **>=date_sub(current_date(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR)**

I've tried several other tests like:

- Adding double quotes to the sql query, but that gives a mysql syntax error.
- Using another way to execute the mysql query through the batch file: `mysql -u user -p****** -D database select...` but this gives the same output as before

If I remove the condition that gives me trouble then the file.csv is successfully created.
Is there any other way to work around this problem?

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: The greater than symbol is a special character in batch.  Escape it by using a carrot. `^>`

Comment: Ok, I added the carrot and the code looks like this ... `^>= date_sub()...` and yes, the sql query now is shown complete in the Command Line, however the same "date_sub(current_date()" file is created and not the file.csv one :(

Comment: I think because you are piping the SELECT command you need to triple escape it. `^^^>`

Comment: Awesome, that did the trick, thanks for the help.

Comment: I know nothing about MySQL but couldn't you just enclose the entire select statement in quotes and execute the query like this: `mysql -u user -p******* -D database -e "select *columns*  from table  *left joins*  where *conditions*  and column >= date_sub(current_date(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR)   order by column INTO OUTFILE 'C:\path\file.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';"`

Comment: No, I tried that one but SQL returns a syntax error near the double quotes, but Squashman20's answer did the trick, the file was created correctly and it's working like a charm.

Comment: Weird.  From what I can read online that should work, but like I said I am no SQL expert.  Someone with MySQL and batch experience would have to comment.